# Class generated from schema using xsd.exe doesn't contain enumeration values

Tags: c#, class, xsd

I have an XSD file that holds values for certain elements in an XML file. I want to write a program that pulls these values from this XSD file so I can make a drop-down menu out of all the values for said elements.

Here is my XSD file in which I want to use each of the values it provides in my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="POSSimpleTypes.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="PRODUCT_STOPType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Version 1.11</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CRUD">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="CRUDType">
                        <xs:enumeration value="P"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="U"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="D"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="SKU_CODE">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="SKUType">
                            <xs:attribute name="owner" type="CODEType" use="optional"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="owner_type" use="optional">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="CONSTANTType">
                                        <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="8"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="STOP_REASON">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="CONSTANTType">
                        <xs:enumeration value="21001"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="21002"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="21003"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="21004"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="21005"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="21006"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="21007"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="21008"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="21009"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LOGIN_NAME" type="NAMEType"/>
            <xs:element name="PROD_STOP_COMMENCE" type="DATEType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="PROD_STOP_END" type="DATEType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="CODE" type="LONG_CODEType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="ORG_UNITS">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="ORGU_CODE">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="CODEType">
                                        <xs:attribute name="type" type="NAMEType" use="required"/>
                                        <xs:attribute name="parent" type="CODEType" use="optional"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="docNo" type="INTEGERType" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="PRODUCT_STOPType" type="PRODUCT_STOPType" />
</xs:schema>
```

When I run the developer command prompt in Visual Studio and convert the file to a class, the generated file looks like this:

```
    public int STOP_REASON {
        get {
            return this.sTOP_REASONField;
        }
        set {
            this.sTOP_REASONField = value;
        }
    }
```

Where are the values listed in the XSD file and how to I retrieve them?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include more of the schema? This is missing parts (`CONSTANTType`) so I can't test it. I thought it might be that the values were numeric and you can't have an enum with numeric values as names. But when I tested a schema with values like that it created an enum like this: `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("200")]
Item200,`

Comment: @ScottHannen I added the full file

Comment: Unfortunately it still has an include that references even more files.

Comment: @ScottHannen Darn. Well, do you know the way to get the enumerated values present in it from the generated class file? How did you get what you mentioned above?

Comment: I hadn't worked with schemas in a while so I searched for another question about something similar using terms like "xsd.exe enumeration restriction." I found a question that included a complete schema. Then I had to Google how to use xsd.exe because I forgot that too. Then I tested what it did if I replaced the enumeration values with numbers.

Comment: My guess is, that your `CONSTANTType` is actually defined as being an int instead of a string. That might throw off the code generator into making it an int instead of an enum.

Comment: @ChristophHerold sorry if this is a dumb question but, where is that usually defined?

Comment: @ChristophHerold Actually how about this: Even if the value is an int, how do I get those from the generated class? That's what I am trying to find out.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but my assumption is, that the xsd tool simply only creates enums for `string` based types with an enumeration restriction. I would need to verify this, though, so don't pin me down to this :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, my assumption about the xsd tool only generating enums for enumeration values defined on `xs:string` types is true. I tried the following simple xml schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="MyClass">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="MyStringEnum">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="Val1" />
              <xs:enumeration value="Val2" />
              <xs:enumeration value="Val3" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="MyIntEnum">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
              <xs:enumeration value="2" />
              <xs:enumeration value="4" />
              <xs:enumeration value="6" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Running the xsd tool on this, produces the following classes:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class MyClass {

    private MyClassMyStringEnum myStringEnumField;

    private int myIntEnumField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public MyClassMyStringEnum MyStringEnum {
        get {
            return this.myStringEnumField;
        }
        set {
            this.myStringEnumField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public int MyIntEnum {
        get {
            return this.myIntEnumField;
        }
        set {
            this.myIntEnumField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd")]
public enum MyClassMyStringEnum {

    /// <remarks/>
    Val1,

    /// <remarks/>
    Val2,

    /// <remarks/>
    Val3,
}
```

As you can easily see, the `enum` for the `xs:string` based member was generated, whereas the `xs:int` based member is created simply as an int type. I'm still looking for the documentation to confirm this, but the test results speak for themselves.

Comment: I tried switching them to strings on my xsd and it worked. Thank you much!